# Error in installation of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, sql-server, sql, service-pack

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express on my machine but I can't find the Management Studio.

[image: im]

I downloaded two versions of SQL Server Management Studio, 2008 and R2

This is the result

[image: im2]

I don't know what is exactly the problem, on my machine I have VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 express for web.

I googled about this topic and i installed the `SP1` package. I had SQL Server 2005 with its management tool and it worked very well, but now I need to change to the 2008's version, I don't know if I made an error when I uninstalled one of them.

[image: im3]

So :

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

What about the **Feature Selection** tab? Have you selected the management Tools in it?

[image]

Check out the options selected in this step-by-step guide:

[Step-by-Step: Installing SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Express after Visual Studio 2010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bethmassi/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010?Redirected=true)